# Qual a melhor forma de evitar sql inject

Tags: php, mysql

Bom tenho 2 formas para me previnir contra sql inject, são elas:

1º

```
$input = $conexao->real_escape_string($input);
```

2º

```
$input = filter_var ($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Query

```
select * from cadastro where nome = '".$input."' LIMIT 1
```

Qual é a melhor forma?

O `real_escape_string` consome recurso do servidor mysql ou php?

Comment: mais aqui https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_se_proteger_do_SQL_Injection

Comment: O `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` por mim é terrível. Ele vai converter outras informações como o `<`, `>` e até o `&`. Na minha opinião o banco de dados deve guardar todo o conteúdo original e usar o `htmlentites` (ou `htmlspecialchars`) na saída da informação, nunca na entrada. Até porque, se utilizar o `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` você vai passar um `<` para `&lt;`, dai você vai fazer um `json_encode` de um valor `&lt;`, não faz menor sentido. Imagina que meu nome de usuário seja`<dev>`, você pegará a informação de `&lt;dev&lr;`. Sobre "consumir recursos", tudo consome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Usando [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) também ajuda

```
 $query = "SELECT* FROM cadastro WHERE nome = :nome LIMIT 1";

 $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindValue(":nome", $input, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Assim, você define que tipo de variável vai para cada parametro `PDO::PARAM_STR`